# Больше нет воска/воску

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, существительные

Оба варианта нормальны?

`У нас больше нет воска/воску.`

Comment: Правильно: _воска_. А существует ли слово _воску_ — не знаю. Скорее всего, нет.

Comment: Звучит нормально.

Comment: Леопольд, а как, по-вашему, звучит «**нет хлебу**»? Если бы Вам сказали, что это возможная форма и привели бы в подтверждением его **нормальности** тот же самый пример, что и в принятом Вами ответе **с чаем**, Вы бы тоже с таким ответом согласились?

Comment: Я пока ничего против «нет воску» сказать не хочу, но меня удивляет Ваша позиция: Вы спрашиваете **про Фому,** Вам отвечают **про Ерёму** — и Вы с радостью соглашаетесь с таким ответом…

Comment: Частный вопрос  желательно решать с учетом общего принципа в данной теме. А иначе это будет всего лишь частный вопрос.  Мы узнаем много нового про ВОСК, но  больше не узнаем НИЧЕГО.  В действительности же там много чего нужно знать.

Comment: Можно критиковать ответы и вопросы, можно обсуждать содержание  ответов и вопросов,  но насколько корректно обсуждать ПРИЕМКУ ответов  (меня удивляет Ваша позиция:,..с радостью соглашаетесь с таким ответом…? Я не знаю...

Comment: Творогу у меня сегодня нетути.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Нет воску***  — возможная форма. К примеру: ***нет чаю***.

Ольга Некрасова. Платит последний (2000)

А Лопатин, склонившись над селектором, быстро и невсерьез обругал секретаршу за то, что до сих пор **нет чаю**...

В. А. Каверин. Открытая книга (1949—1956)
Сторож берет мой чемодан, ведет меня в общежитие и бормочет в ответ на расспросы, что начальства нет, **чаю нет** и хорошо еще, если найдется свободная койка.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**  от 18.10.2023

**[Ответы Грамоты.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83)**

**Формы на -у, -ю** вещественных и некоторых других существительных (рюмка коньяку, чашка чаю, килограмм сахару) имеют **количественное значение**, обозначают часть целого. Ср. без количественного значения: производство коньяка, белизна сахара, вкус чая. **Раньше формы на -у, -ю считались предпочтительнее, если речь шла о части целого.** В наши дни такие формы употребляются всё реже и происходит **выравнивание** по основной модели, не связанной с определенным значением. Сейчас наряду с формой чашка чаю вполне допустима (а многими даже предпочитается) форма **чашка чая**. Формы на -у, -ю обычно сохраняются в словосочетании, где существительное зависит **от глагола:** выпить чаю, поесть супу, добавить сахару. При этом сочетания выпить чая и выпить чай тоже возможны.

Все варианты правильные. В современном литературном языке в количественном (партитивном) значении род. п. в **письменной** речи преобладает форма на -а (чашка чая). Но в **разговорной речи** часто употребляется флексия -у, особенно в глагольных конструкциях со значением неполного объекта (хочу чаю, добавить сахару и т. п.). Винительный падеж (хочу чай) также возможен, т. к. речь идет о конкретном объекте.

**Материал из статьи** **[Историческая морфология](https://uchebana5.ru/cont/1808524-p10.html) .**

В результате влияния одного склонения на другое появилось большое количество вариантных окончаний в современном 2 склонении, так как оно претерпело **наибольшие изменения** в своем составе (пополнилось существительными **3, 4, 5 древних склонений**, а также разносклоняемыми, которые и принести во второе склонение **свои окончания, ставшие вариантными**).

Так, в **родительном и предложном падежах** единственного числа наряду с исконными окончаниями –а (-я) (Р.п.), -е (П.п) стали употребляться как вариантные окончания –у (-ю). Например: ложка меда – ложка меду, выйти из дома – выйти из дому, в лесу – в лесе, в доме –на дому.  Оно встречается также **в устойчивых оборотах**, характерных для устной речи: без году неделя, с глазу на глаз, со смеху умереть и др.

Окончание -у в родительном падеже усвоили **вещественные** (меду, сахару, чаю), **абстрактные,** допускающие, количественные изменения (много шуму, смеху), **собирательные** (народу), **пространственные** с предлогами из, до, с (из дому, из лесу) существительные. Существительные всех этих лексико-грамматических разрядов входили в **3 древнее склонение**, поэтому за ними и закрепилось окончание –у как вариантное.

**Обобщенный материал о вариантных окончаниях с примерами**

1. **ВАРИАНТНОЕ ОКОНЧАНИЕ «У/Ю» С КОЛИЧЕСТВЕННЫМ ЗНАЧЕНИЕМ**

(1) Вариантное окончание У/Ю для существительных м.р. в Р.п., наряду с основным окончанием А/Я, используется в вещественных существительных при указании на часть или количество, **в том числе со словами отрицания при отсутствии количества:** выпить чаю (или чая), чашка чая (или чаю), нет сахара или сахару.

(2) В именных сочетаниях чаще используется окончание У/Ю, а в глагольных – окончание А/Я.

(3) Окончание У/Ю с количественным значением используется также в абстрактных и собирательных существительных: много шума или шуму, мало народу или народа.

**ТЕКСТОВЫЕ ПРИМЕРЫ**

Я предложил отцу ее стакан пуншу, Дуне подал я чашку чаю.

За чашкой шоколада я читал журналы.

«Как так – нет сахару? – удивляется Таня. – Есть!»

Прошу вас, чашечку кофе. Правда, у нас нет сахара.

Микки охотится за кусочками сыра.

В английских фильмах герои пьют чашечку бульона, если простыли.

Тебе надо выпить бульону, подкрепиться.

«Много шума из ничего» – пьеса Уильяма Шекспира.

Много шуму – мало проку.

2. **ОСОБЕННОСТИ РЕШЕНИЯ ОРФОГРАММЫ**

(1) Если количественное значение отсутствует, то пишется только окончание А/Я: плантация чая, выпуск шелка.

(2) При наличии определения пишется окончание А/Я: стакан горячего чая.

(3) В существительных с суффиксом **К** пишется окончание У/Ю: **выпить чайку, взять сахарку.**

(4) **В устойчивых выражениях** для существительных м.р. в Р.п. используется одна из форм: ни слуху ни духу, без году неделя, без племени и роду, не зная броду – не суйся в воду (окончание У), но: без страха и упрека (окончание А).

(5) Окончания А/Я и У/Ю могут различаться **по смыслу:** выйти из дОма, проводить до дОма (окончание А, дом как строение), но: выйти из дому, проводить дО дому (окончание У, свой дом).

**ТЕКСТОВЫЕ ПРИМЕРЫ**

В Шри-Ланки расположены большие плантации чая.

Он выпил стакан горячего, душистого чая.

Выпей чайку – забудешь тоску.

Послушай, Ибрагим, ты человек одинокий, без роду и племени.

В первые дни все известия были в пользу бежавших: ни слуху, ни духу, пропали да и только.

Он был настоящим рыцарем без страха и упрека.

Он вышел из дома и пошел пешком до извозчика.

Однажды в студеную зимнюю пору я из дому вышел.

Comment: А почему Вы примеры привели **с чаем, а не с воском**? Вопрос-то был про «**нет воску**»!

Comment: Тут дело не в конкретном примере, а в самой теме. Конкретный пример лишь вписывается в общий подход к решению задачи.  Именно так я поняла вопрос. Надо было обозначить возможность ВАРИАНТОВ.

Comment: Sharon: «_Тут дело не в конкретном примере, а в самой теме. Конкретный пример лишь вписывается в общий подход к решению задачи. Именно так я поняла вопрос. Надо было обозначить возможность ВАРИАНТОВ_». === Но почему-то Вы **ни одного примера** с «нет воску» в даже сейчас дополненном своём ответе не привели! А вот почему — это для меня загадка…

Comment: Не могу же я обыскать весь Интернет)  Но думаю, что где-нибудь этот воск можно найти.  Кроме того, надо было найти фразу БОЛЬШЕ НЕТ ВОСКА/ВОСКУ, а в другом ответе тоже нет слова БОЛЬШЕ. А вот почему — это для меня загадка… Ведь есть же разница между  "больше нет" и просто "нет".

Answer (score 5):

В орфографическом словаре: [**воск**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA), *-а* и *-у*.

Форма на ***-у*** — это второй родительный падеж (или количественно-отделительный, или партитив); образуется как производное от родительного падежа и отвечает на его же вопросы, выражает значение части по отношению к целому.

Правильно: *У нас **больше нет воска**.*
У нас больше нет снега (мёда, сахара, кипятка).

*— Вот посмотрите! — говорит Франциска, берет ножницы и игральную карту, складывает ее вчетверо, вырезает из нее кружок вроде бублика, обматывает его гарусом ярко-желтого цвета, позвякивает вокруг него ножницами — и получается пушистый цыпленок, будто сейчас из яйца. — Жалко, **нет воска** для клюва. Вон сколько у нас журавлей без носов!* (К. И. Чуковский. Серебряный герб).

Правильно: воску (в партитиве).

*Купив у разносчика-овернца **немного воску** и несколько лент, она могла рассказать мессиру барону о всех самых важных событиях, происходящих во французском королевстве* (А. Голон. Анжелика. Маркиза Ангелов).