# Главное — набираться опыту/опыта

Tags: грамматика

А откудова в род. падеже эта форма на *-у* в мужском роде? Корректно ли её вместо формы на *-а*, например, на ОГЭ использовать? Или только в неформальной речи?

> Я от **страху** (вместо *страха*) этого отучался долго — года.

> Главное — набираться **опыту** (вместо *опыта*).

Comment: Вы про _воск_ уже спрашивали то же; Римма дала вам нужный ответ: там подробно объяснили этот случай, сказали про такой падеж, как претитив. Но вы снова задали вопрос по этому поводу.

Comment: Откудова — это на каком языке? Соблюдайте информационный стиль при записи вопросов. Также было бы неплохо, если бы вы сами предлагали какое-либо решение. (Это замечание ко всем вопросам.) Ведь есть источники, где все это объясняется.   Вот у меня книжечка Гольцова Русский язык (10 – 11 класс), 2007 год, Тема варианты падежных окончаний для существительных. У Розенталя, наверное, есть.

Comment: Этот, вполне хороший, вопрос вы задавали — вот: [Больше нет воска/воску](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475793/%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83) Либо вы забываете легко, либо не знаю зачем вы задаете одни и те же вопросы.

Comment: Там есть ответ на вопрос "откудова?".  А вот правильность конкретных слов можно проверить по текстам (Нацкорпус, Примеры предложений  https://sinonim.org/p/опыту и т. д.).  Форма НАБИРАТЬСЯ ОПЫТУ не проходит, а форма СО СТРАХА/СО СТРАХУ имеет одинаковую частотность. Вот и делаем выводы.

Comment: А вот словарь:  СТРАХ
Управление в русском языке
СТРАХ [тревога; боязнь] чего / перед кем-чем / (устар.) к чему. Страх смерти; Страх наказания; Страх перед учителем; Страх перед неминуемой расплатой; Страх перед жизнью хорошо испытан мною (М. Г.); В детстве мы чувствовали страх к серому кресту (Бун.). От страха, со страха, со страху.  А для слова ОПЫТ нет формы "опыту".

Comment: Что можно еще добавить? Возможно, есть источники, где сравниваются эти формы.  Поэтому закрывать вопрос не надо, как я думаю. Именно из-за конкретики слов.